# how to stop re-calling ng-style and ng-class directive binding with method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have method that will return the 'css styles' based on JSON (which will contain css properties) that i'm binding with directive which should execute first time (while page load or when ever JSON properties gets changed) but it's executing every mouseover of the page. I'm not sure why it's happening. Please let me know i need to elaborate more.

My code Like:

```
 scope.getLayoutProperties=function(){
                var layoutPropValues='';
                if(scope.layoutData) {  
                    angular.forEach(scope.layoutData.collections.weblayoutproperties.rowset,function(layoutPropValue,layoutPropKey){        
                        if(layoutPropValue.layoutlayoutid==scope.layout.layoutlayoutid){
                            if(layoutPropValue.weblayoutpropertyname=="background-image"){
                                var layoutBGClass=classCreatorForBackgroundImage(layoutPropValue.weblayoutpropertyvalue,layoutPropValue.layoutlayoutid);
                                removeClasses=[];
                                removeClasses.push(layoutBGClass);
                                classDestroyer(removeClasses);                                      
                                element.addClass(layoutBGClass);
                            }else{
                                scope.layoutProperties[layoutPropValue.weblayoutpropertyname] = layoutPropValue.weblayoutpropertyvalue;
                                layoutPropValues = JSON.stringify(scope.layoutProperties);
                                layoutPropValues = layoutPropValues.replace(/[{("")}]/g, '');
                                layoutPropValues = layoutPropValues.replace(/,/g, ';'); 
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                element.css(scope.layoutProperties);
                return layoutPropValues;            
            };
```

This method calling in directive like this

```
layoutObj.template = "<div "
            + "page-object='pageObject' "
            + "layout-data='layoutData' "
            + "mapper-data='mapperData' "
            + "style='' "
            + " layoutid='{{layout.layoutlayoutid}}' " 
            + " id='{{layout.layoutlayoutid}}' " 
            + " ng-click='layoutClick($event)' "
            + " ng-style='{{getLayoutProperties()}}' "
            + " ng-mouseleave='hideLayoutHandle($event)' "
            + "class='weblayout weblayoutselection col-lg-480 col-md-480 col-sm-480 col-xs-480'> <div class='row layoutrow'> "
            + "<div class='layouthandle layout-settings webcontrol-settings'>" 
            + " <ul><li>"           
            +"<a><i id='repeat' class='fa fa-repeat disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='trash' class='fa fa-trash-o disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='up' class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='down' class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down disabledfornow' ></i></a>"
            +"<a><i id='edit' class='fa fa-gear' ></i></a>"
            +"</li> </ul>" 
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>";
```

Comment: i don't know what you are doing but it doesn't seem right

Comment: You add `ng-mouseleave`, also check `hideLayoutHandle`

Comment: @TanDuong - ng-mouseleave  code -  scope.hideLayoutHandle = function(event) {
   var layoutId = $(event.target).closest(".weblayout").attr("id");
   $('#'+ layoutId).find('.layouthandle').css('display','none');
   };

Comment: @TanDuong - It's keep on firing when mouse hover on this directive(div). I don't know why it's happening? what could be the reason?

Comment: @bagya: I think you need to refractor your code  using `ng-repeat`. Don't bind event like that. Try to `console.log` inside function to check which function is still running when you mouse over

Comment: may be short answer is - use :: ... But I really advice you to learn some angular... cause this is something different.